# How to print elements from a data structure

Tags: c#

My code doesn't work properly, I don't know how to print all elements which are elements in a data structure. I have List and in that list are all numbers which are divisible with 10 and 0, other numbers don't go in List, I mean they are ignored. Well, my program work but it prints 0 instead numbers which is divisible with 10 and 0. Program asks a user to enter numbers until he press number 0. When he presses 0 program stop working and print numbers which are divisible with two numbers which I already said. Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Vjezba8_kolokvij1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int broj;

            List<int> listaBrojeva = new List<int>();

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unesite broj: ");
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out broj);

                if ((broj != 0) && (broj % 10 == 0))
                {
                    listaBrojeva.Add(broj);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Krivi unos.");
                }
            } while (broj != 0);
            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach(int no in listaBrojeva)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(broj);
            }
            foreach(int no in listaBrojeva)
            {
                Console.Write("{0},", broj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's just a typo, replace broj with no

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't writing out the values in the list, you are writing out `broj`, which will always be zero because you are terminating the while loop only when this becomes `0`.

Change

```
        foreach(int no in listaBrojeva)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(broj);
        }
```

to

```
        foreach(int no in listaBrojeva)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(no);
        }
```